# How to extract multidimensional array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which is in following format

```
{
    "items": {
        "0": 96,
        "1": 121566,
        "3": "2014-10-30"
    },
    "name": [
        "asdfghj"
    ],
    "misc": [
        {
            "VehicleBrandName": "FORD",
            "VehicleTypeName": "111111"
        },
        {
            "VehicleBrandName": "BMW",
            "VehicleTypeName": "75676576"
        },
        {
            "VehicleBrandName": "FORD",
            "VehicleTypeName": "2222"
        }
    ]
}
```

here items,name,misc are values from different table. Items passed as an object and name and misc are arrays.

In jquery function

```
var misc = data.misc;
var items = data.items;
var name = data.customer;
$.each(items, function (key, value) {// working function
    part = $('.check').find('*[data-field="' + key + '"]');
    part.val(value);
});
$(misc).each(function (key, value) {//not working
   for (name in value) {
      if (value.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
         part = $('.check').find('*[table-field="' + name + '"]');
         part.text(value[name]);
       }
   }
   $('tr.active').clone().appendTo('tbody');
});
```

And HTML code is

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped check" id="TableAppend">
   <tbody class="items">
      <tr class="active">
         <td style="font-size: 12px;" width="70"><p table-field="VehicleBrandName"></p></td>
         <td style="font-size: 12px;" width="70"><p table-field="VehicleTypeName"></p></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

items are working fine. But misc is getting only single value.Other two values are not getting.
I expecting the following output.

```
FORD       BMW        FORD 
111111     75676576   2222
```

Please help me......

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: I don't think "$(misc).each(function (key, value)" is where the problem is, you need to use `.find('*[table-field="' + key + '"]'` or something.

Comment: What do you mean by 'is not getting any value'? [Your loop works correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/m3n832ro/) based on the code provided - I'm able to `console.log` the variables inside the `$(misc).each` loop...

Comment: what is not working?I tried to loop over data your code is working

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? In your code you are just overwrite the html, and get "FORD

2222" as a result.

http://jsfiddle.net/4u1wtgm0/

Comment: By the way you do not have an array. You have an object and the arrays are only "misc" and "names". Try do do the same with native JavaScript (using "for" only) to understand how it works.

Comment: I want all the three values @Max and thank you for the comment

Comment: Is there need to append the each result?

Comment: @shadowwalker You have only one row but you have 3 values in the array, so the row only gets the last value. If you need all 3 items to show, either you need 3 rows, or you need to append a new row for each value.

Comment: @artm I tried to appending. But not worked

Comment: If you need all, than take a look at jquery clone(). You'll need to clone <tr class="active"> inside you "if (value.hasOwnProperty(name))", fill it with you data and append to tbody

Comment: @Max not worked inside of "if (value.hasOwnProperty(name))" and outside of for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 part = $('.check').find('*[table-field="' + name + '"]');
```

try

```
part = $('.active').find('*[table-field="' + name + '"]');
```

because you have `class=active` for `table-field`.

you can try something like this:

```
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){ 

   var json=JSON.parse('{"items":{"0":96,"1":121566,"3":"2014-10-30"},"name":["asdfghj"],"misc":[{"VehicleBrandName":"FORD","VehicleTypeName":"111111"},{"VehicleBrandName":"BMW","VehicleTypeName":"75676576"},{"VehicleBrandName":"FORD","VehicleTypeName":"2222"}]}');
var misc=json.misc;
console.log(json);
var string1=""; 
var string2="";
           $(misc).each(function (key, value) {//not working

               for (name in value) { 
                   if (value.hasOwnProperty(name)) {  
                     part = $('.active').find('*[table-field="' + name + '"]');
                    // 
                    if(parseInt(value[name])%1== 0){
                    string1=string1+"  "+value[name];   
                    part.text(string1);   
                    $('.active').append(part);  
                    }else{
                        string2=string2+"  "+value[name];
                        part.text(string2);
                         $('.active').append(part);
                    }    

                   }
               }

            });

    });

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way:

```
var $tr = $('tr.active');
$(misc).each(function (key, value) {
   var $newTr = $tr.clone();
   $('[table-field="VehicleBrandName"]', $newTr).text(value.VehicleBrandName);
    $('[table-field="VehicleTypeName"]', $newTr).text(value.VehicleTypeName);

    $newTr.appendTo('tbody')
});
$tr.remove()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rz4uswen/1/

Comment: Thank you.It worked. I tried to generalize that function. If more no of table-field contain, the code will very length.If database field name is given to table-field, then is it possible to get field name in this function so that I can generalize??